# A summation proof

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction

Prove **USING INDUCTION** ($\mathbb{N}$ starting $1$) that: $\sum_{n=a}^{b}f(n) = \sum_{n=0}^{b-a} f(b-n)$

I found this property of summations in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation), but I haven't been able to prove it. Here's my attempt:

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a<b$.

1. Base case: if $b=a+1$,
   \begin{align*}
       \sum_{n=0}^{b-a} f(b-n) &= \sum_{n=0}^{(a+1)-a} f(a+1-n)\\
       &= \sum_{n=0}^{1} f(a+1-n)\\
       &= f(a+1-0) + \sum_{n=1}^{1} f(a+1-n)\\
       &= f(a+1) + f(a+1-1)\\
       &= f(a+1) + f(a)\\
       &= f(a) + f(a+1)\\
       &= \sum_{n=a}^{a+1} f(n)\\
       &= \sum_{n=a}^{b} f(n)
     \end{align*}
2. Assume that it is true for $b=a+k$, for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, that is to say, supposed that:
   \begin{align*}
       \sum_{n=a}^{a+k}f(n) &= \sum_{n=0}^{(a+k)-a} f(a+k-n)\\
       &= \sum_{n=0}^{k} f(a+k-n)
     \end{align*}
3. For $b=a+k+1$ we get:
   \begin{align*}
       \sum_{n=0}^{b-a}f(b-n) &= \sum_{n=0}^{(a+k+1)-a} f((a+k+1)-n)\\
       &= \sum_{n=0}^{k+1} f(a+k+1-n)\\
       &= \text{What goes next?}
     \end{align*}

that's as far as I get.

Comment: There is no need for a proof. You are just reindexing your sum. Set $n=b-k$ and use $k$ instead as your index.

Comment: Just write it out.

Comment: The left is the sum over all $n$ between $a$ and $b$ (inclusive). The right is the sum over all $n$ between $b$ and $a$ (inclusive). Done.

Comment: I understand that intuitively is true, but I'm trying to get the formal proof. If it's so "trivial" there must be a way to prove it without arguing that "there is no need for a proof".

Comment: I think the base case would be $b-a=0$.

Comment: @martycohen sorry I didn't specify I'm working with naturals starting in 1, so $b-a=1 \Rightarrow b=a+1$.

Comment: @Darvid writing it out *is* a proof.  The left-hand side is $f(a) + f(a+1) + \cdots + f(b)$.  The right-hand side is $f(b) + f(b-1) + \cdots f(a)$.  They're the same.

Comment: I believe what I've written is a proof, Darvid. It says both sides are the sum of the same numbers, hence, equal.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose
$\sum_{n=a}^{b}f(n) 
= \sum_{n=0}^{b-a} f(b-n)
$
is true for
$b-a=m$.
This means
$b=a+m$
so
$\sum_{n=a}^{a+m}f(n) 
= \sum_{n=0}^{m} f(a+m-n)
$

Then,
if $b-a=m+1$,
$b=a+m+1$ so

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=a}^{b}f(n) 
&=\sum_{n=a}^{a+m+1}f(n)\\ 
&=\sum_{n=a}^{a+n}f(n)+f(a+m+1)\\ 
&=\sum_{n=0}^m f(n+a)+f(a+m+1)\\ 
&=\sum_{n=0}^m f(a+m-n)+f(a+m+1)\\ 
&=\sum_{n=-1}^m f(a+m-n)\\ 
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m+1} f(a+m-(n-1))\\ 
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m+1} f(a+m+1-n)\\ 
&=\sum_{n=0}^{b-a} f(b-n)\\ 
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Consider f(b - n) for all $n\in[0, b-a]$

When n = 0, f(b - n) = f(b)

When n = 1, f(b - n) = f(b - 1)

…

When n = b - a, f(b - n) = f(a)

Thus you get all the same terms as on the right, but in reverse order. Since addition is associative, the sums are equal. $\blacksquare$

Comment: thanks for the intuitive idea, I was hoping to get the formal proof using induction.

Comment: The above is a formal proof. But no, not an inductive proof.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams, Regarding your most recent question that you deleted, sgn((sgn)+0.5) will work